# How to piggyback an MSI installer within an MSI installer

Tags: windows-installer

This is my first time attempting to use Windows Installer to build a setup package (our client does not wish to use Wix, which I have worked with extensively). Currently I have an MSI that builds and works as intended. However, I need to add an installer for an SDK that is required for the program I have written to work on other machines. I have added the second installer (also an MSI) as a Custom Action which executes based on whether you tick a checkbox during the installation process. The problem is, when the second installer executes, I get the error that there is already a setup being run on the system and the installation cannot continue. How can I get around this? The custom action is set to run during Install.

Thanks in advance for any help in solving this problem.

Comment: What tool are you using to author the MSI?  This would help give you a specific answer.

Comment: I am building this in VS2010 using a Setup Project (sorry, that's what I meant when I said Windows Installer).

Comment: Take a look at my FOSS proct on Codeplex 'ISWIX'.  You can use it to author wxs merge modules  (Files and Folders designer) and then consume that module in a wxs product.   This allows the customer to drag and drop changes but still have to learn wix to make other changes.  Basically 90% coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup Projects are notorious for the limitations and quality in authoring that they provide. So much that MSFT has removed them from Visual Studio 11 and replaced them with InstallShield Limited Edition.

Your best bet is to look into the setup.exe bootstrapper that Setup Project use.  Take a look at the XML format that drives them and make your SDK installer a simple silent installer that can be driven by this infrastructure prior to the invocation of the main MSI that you are working on now.

InstallShield (Setup Prereqs and Suite Installers ) and WiX ( Burn ) would both be far more capable tools for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two MSI packages install at the same time, more specifically you cannot launch another MSI during the InstallExecuteSequence of another one. However, if you trigger your custom action in the UI sequence this is posssible.

Comment: What do you mean by triggering it in the UI sequence? I've attempted to run the custom action in the Install phase and Commit phase. The only other two options I have are Rollback and Uninstall

Comment: It's a bad idea.  First, assuming your tool could author this which it can't,  you'd limit support for silent installations as the UI sequence isn't processed during /QN or /QB.  It is processed during /QR but that's a complete hack.   You'd have to do extensive post build manipulation of the output MSI to inject the authoring that you need that Setup Projects don't support.